# Prove triangle inequality for complex series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

[image]

First thing I notice is the strict inequality.. shouldn't it be $\leq$?

In any case, how can I do this one?

Comment: Considering how the bottom half of the sigmas are cut off, maybe the same happened to the $\leq$ sign? Anyhow, one technique is to show the sequence of partial sums of Cauchy convergent and then use the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, it should be $\leq$.

Also, note that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_k |$ is a series with positive terms, thus the limit exists (might not be convergent).

**Hint** Prove by induction and use:

$$ | \sum_{k=1}^N a_k | \leq  \sum_{k=1}^N |a_k | (*)\,.$$

If the limit on the LHS exists, then as the limit on the RHS exists, by taking limits you are done.

If the limit on the LHS does not exist, it is not clear what the problem means by that inequality. I would guess, and you can prove this, that by $| \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k |$ it is understood any limit point of a subsequence of $| \sum_{k=1}^N a_k |$. Using $(*)$ you can easily prove that the limit of any convergent subsequence of $| \sum_{k=1}^N a_k |$ is  $ \leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_k |$.

Note that there are two potential issues here, which makes the problem unclear to me in this case: it is possible that $| \sum_{k=1}^N a_k | $ is convergent even if $\sum_{k=1}^N a_k$ is not, or neither is convergent.

Comment: yeah i agree this is a weird problem.. i'll work with this for a bit and come back with progress.

Comment: Okay, I've got something.

consider $|\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1} z_k|$. We can write this as $|\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} z_k + \sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{n+1} z_k|$.


Then applying the triangle inequality, this is $\leq |\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}z_k| + |\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{n+1}z_k|$. But this first term is, by our hypothesis, $\leq \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}|z_k|$ and the second term is $\leq \sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{n+1}|z_k|$ by the base case. Thus the proof is complete.

Comment: @terribleatmath Yes, that`s exactly the proof of that inequality.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! is this enough to show that the result holds for the infinite sums as well, or is there a little wrapping up to do for that?

Comment: @terribleatmath To prove the infinite series case you just take the limit. BUT, if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is divergent, what does the left hand side of the series inequality mean?

Comment: well, it means nothing essentially. absolute value of infinity is not a defined concept

Comment: @terribleatmath Well $|\infty|=\infty$ but the issue is that the series might be divergent because it doesn't have a limit...

Comment: thats correct. also is $|-\infty| = \infty$?

Comment: @terribleatmath Yes. If a function or a sequence/series has the limit $- \infty$, then the absolute value has a limit of $+ \infty$.....Also, the equality $| \infty |=\infty$ holds even if the LHS is the complex infinite while the RHS is the real $+ \infty$.